# Embedding Loops with 2 Variables

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, copyToCell As Range

For j = 9 To 23

         For i = 2 To 23
                 Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet A").Range(Cells(3, j), Cells(11, j))
                 Set copyToCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet B").Cells(3, i)
                 
                  For Each cell In rng
                    If cell.Value <> vbNullString Then
                    copyToCell.Value = cell.Value
                    Set copyToCell = copyToCell.Offset(1, 0)
                    End If
                  Next cell
                               
                               
         i = i + 2
        Next i
        
j = j + 2
Next j
```

I'm trying to copy an array of cells from one sheet and have them pasted to another. The code I wrote places the values that are copied from "Sheet A" to "Sheet B" correctly, however, the values are incorrect.

[image: Sheet A]

The pic above is Sheet A. I'm trying to copy values from Range I3:Ill (Sheet A) and then have them pasted to the following Sheet B Range B3:B11 and so on for each plan listed.

[image: Sheet B]

I created a loop so that the values under Plan 2 and so on in Sheet A will transfer those values under Plan 2 and so on in Sheet B.

When I run my code it results in all 0's in each plan on Sheet B instead of 5,5,4 (under Plan 1) and 5 (under plan 2). Any ideas or another way around it besides having to use 2 variables in a loop?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the loop? Just put the loop values in the Range statements:

```
  Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, copyToCell As Range

  Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(9, "j"), Cells(23, "j"))
  Set copyToCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, "i")
 
  rng.Copy copyToCell

End Sub
```

HTH

Comment: Got it. I think I was just over thinking it. I'll post the code when I got it. Thanks!